# Creating a sidenav with a fixed search bar at the top (AngularMaterial2)

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, navbar

Several times in the past have I had an app where I have a sidenav with a lot of navigation option, where amount exceeds the height of the sidenav.

To help with the UX part, I want to include a textbox at the top of the sidenav, which will be fixed at the top and won't move even if the navbar is scrolled down.

I've only succeeded putting the textbox inside of the sidenav, but not making it fixed at the top.

I've tried approaching it using CSS, with either `position: fixed` or `position: absolute`, and many thing I've since forgotten, but none have worked. I've managed positioning it at the place I want, but the background had disappeared, and it's not taking place inside the actual sidenav, as the navigation links appear behind the textbox.

I haven't seen a similar approach in other sites, so I haven't had a place to take example from.
The basics are as shown at https://material.angular.io/, except that there should be a textbox on top, to help filter links in the navbar.

Comment: Try this https://medium.com/@MikkelDamm/sticky-header-in-angular2-90364eba81d9

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure what you really want... but I think that this is a great place to try and use a technique I recently ran across. You can use `transform: translate(x,x)` to create a new context for `fixed` positioning. Usually `fixed` would respect the *body* as it's boundery - but using translate on an element seems to create it's own child scope for fixed positioning.

```
.parent {
  transform: translate(0,0);
}

.parent .form {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent .sidebar-module-list {
  padding-top: {{formHeight}};
}
```

[Here is an example CodePen](http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/JNowNX/)